# How to load react-native-map on android application

Tags: android, react-native

I have below code to use react-native-map on an android Genymotion simulator. And I followed the instruction from https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md to setup the dependencies. But when I run react-native run-android, it doesn't show the UI. Instead, it shows a while page with a line in the middle. I am able to load the map on an ios device with the similar code. What wrong with my code for android?

```
import React, {


AppRegistry,
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  ListView,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Dimensions,
 //MapView,
} from 'react-native';

import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    padding: 30,
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  inputText: {
    height: 36,
      padding: 4,
      marginRight: 5,
      flex: 4,
      fontSize: 18,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#48BBEC',
      borderRadius: 8,
      color: '#48BBEC'
  }
});

class MapPage extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            region:{
                latitude: 4.21048,
                longitude: 101.97577,
            latitudeDelta: 10,
            longitudeDelta: 5
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput style={styles.inputText}></TextInput>
                <MapView 
                    style={ styles.map }
                    mapType={"standard"}
                    region={this.state.region}
                    zoomEnabled={true}
                    scrollEnabled={true}
                    showsScale={true}
                  ></MapView>
            </View>
            )
    }
}

module.exports = MapPage;
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this issue  @Zhao i am facing same issue

Comment: No I didn't use react-native map. Instead I am using leaflet.

Comment: okay Thanks @Zhao

Comment: @Zhao which leaflet library used for react native?